# Losing object reference on lookup in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension for Google Chrome and I ran into the following situation:

I'm trying to get all the existing tabs from all the opened windows in the same instance of Google Chrome. I manage to get them and construct an array of objects that contain the relevant data for me.

When I look at the constructed array using console.log (which is saved for future use also) I can see the collection of objects, but I can't reference them (when I try I get undefined).

I tried to save the array outside my object in a container, but nothing changes.

Any idea why the reference to the objects go away when I try to look them up? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
(function(window){
    //defining a namespace
    var example = {
        bmarksmaster: (function() {
            var bmarksmaster = function() {
                return new bmarksmaster.fn.init();
            }

            bmarksmaster.fn = bmarksmaster.prototype = {
                    debug: false,
                    tabs: [],
                    constructor: bmarksmaster,

                    init: function() {
                        return this;
                    },

                    windowParser: function(ctx, filter) {
                        var local = ctx;
                        var filter = filter;
                        return function(wObj) {
                            if((wObj !== null) && (wObj !== undefined)) {
                                for(var idx in wObj) {
                                    var cw = wObj[idx];
                                    if((cw.tabs !== null) && (cw.tabs !== undefined)) {
                                        var cwtabs = cw.tabs;
                                        for(var tabIdx in cwtabs) {
                                                  local.tabs.push(filter(tabIdx, cwtabs[tabIdx]));

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        };
                    },

                    getTabs: function() {
                        var returnData = [];
                        chrome.windows.getAll(
                            {
                                "populate": true
                            }, this.windowParser(this, function(i, e) {
                                var data = {};
                                if(!e.incognito) {
                                    data["title"] = e.title;
                                    data['url'] = e.url;
                                    data['favicon'] = e.favIconUrl || "";
                                }
                                return data;
                            }));

                        return this.tabs;
                    },

                    getTab: function(callback) {
                        this.getTabs();
                        for (var tabIdx in this.tabs) {
                            if(callback(tabIdx, this.tabs[tabIdx])) {
                                return this.tabs[tabIdx];
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    getTabsData: function(callback) {
                        var data = [];
                        var tabs = [];
                        tabs = this.getTabs();
                        console.log(this.tabs[0]);
                        for (var tabIdx in tabs) {
                            console.log(tabs[tabIdx]);
                            var tabData = callback(tabIdx, tabs[tabIdx]);  
                            if(tabData) {
                                data.push(tabData);
                            }
                        }
                        return data;
                    },

                    setDebug: function() {
                        this.debug = true;
                    },

                    resetDebug: function() {
                        this.debug = false;
                    }
            };

            bmarksmaster.fn.init.prototype = bmarksmaster.fn;

            return bmarksmaster;
        })()
    };
    window.example = example;
})(window);
//end of bmarksmaster.js file

    console.log(example.bmarksmaster().getTabs()); //this works, I can see the array
    console.log(example.bmarksmaster().getTabs()[0]); //this doesn't work, I get undefined, never mind the shortcut
```

Comment: This looks very strange to me:

    `var index = local.tabs.length;
    local.tabs[index++] = filter(tabIdx, cwtabs[tabIdx]);`
Why are you incrementing index?

Also, can you post the result from `.getTabs()` ?

Comment: The result from .getTabs() is something like this (using console.log): [{favicon: "", title: "", url: ""}, {favicon: "", title: "", url: ""}, ...]

Comment: Edit: I removed that piece of code you were talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic in your code is wrong. It is a bit convoluted and hard to follow. I would recommend rewriting it a bit to be simpler. Something like this might help get you started. It collects all the windows, putts all the tabs into the `tabs` var.

```
var tabs = [];
chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true}, function(windows) {
  var localTabs = windows.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a.tabs.concat(b.tabs);
  });
  tabs = localTabs.filter(function(element){
    return !element.incognito;
  });
})
```